Blocking Apps on MacOS
Is there a way to block a list of specific apps on macOS?
I have looked up solutions such as Cisdem, but there are some holes in the way it works that I don't like.
Unless you also block Activity Monitor, Terminal, and System Preferences, you can simply quit the Cisdem process or create a new user to get around it.
You have to block Activity Monitor, Terminal, and System Preferences to make it work well.
I want to block an app from running or even being installed on my Mac. The app can be installed via the App Store and the web. Not sure how to go about this. Enabling Parental Controls won't work as Administrator privileges are needed.
The specific app I want to block is Apple Configurator.
Any ideas?

Are you the admin on the Mac in question?

If someone is an admin, then they can configure anything that can be configured.

It’s a bit of setup to block one app, but it should do the trick if you can’t find another method.

https://github.com/google/santa

If you can keep admin access away from the person who is trying to run and install this, it simplifies your life substantially since with enough knowledge, such access generally can’t be defeated.
